# Uploading An Image As A ByteArray to a Blob using AS3 & AMFPHP

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, amfphp

I'm currently having a bit of an issue when I try to upload a photo taking using an iOS camera to a MySQL database using PHP and unfortunately have been unable to find the right help online.

Basically The User takes a photo on their iOS device and I take that raw MediaPromise and put it into a ByteArray. I then call a PHP function using AMFPHP to add the binary to a Blob in my database. But when I test the whole thing, it never seems to work. Could somebody maybe help me with this problem or at least point me in the right direction? It would be highly appreciated. Here's the code:

AS3:

```
var dataSource:IDataInput;

function imageSelected1(event:MediaEvent) {


var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
dataSource = imagePromise.open();

 if( imagePromise.isAsync )  {
var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher; 
   eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onDataComplete );

}
  else {
        readMediaData();
  }

    }

// PHP Connection //

// Database //
var gw2:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
gw2.connect(connectiongoeshere);


    // Responder //
var pictureresponder:Responder = new Responder(onpicture);



    function onpicture(pictureobj:Object) {
        gotoAndStop(1);

}


 function onDataComplete( event:Event ):void {
   readMediaData();
  }


        function readMediaData() {

                   var imageBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                   //dataSource.readBytes( imageBytes );

                   dataSource.readBytes(imageBytes);


                gw2.call("class.setData", pictureresponder, imageBytes);

                }
```

PHP:

```
    function setData($ba) {
       // Connecting to the database //


mysql_pconnect("hi", "hi", "hi");
mysql_select_db("hi");

 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users set profilepicture2 ='$ba->data' WHERE email= 'email@gmail.com'");
return $result;

}
```

Comment: First your `var imageBytes:ByteArray` is declared inside, declare it outside like you did with `var dataSource:IDataInput;`, the function should **only update**, not create. a variable). Second, why using `NetConnection`? If that's for server uploading, shouldn't you use a `URLRequest` with **post** options?... Anyways, see if this **[example source](https://github.com/braitsch/as3-bitmap-snapshot/blob/master/libs/com/quietless/bitmap/BitmapSnapshot.as)** is useful. Just remove any **public** or **private** texts from variables & functions (since your code is on the timeline? right?)...

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much. Should I not be using NetConnection as I'm using AMFPHP?

Comment: In the past, to get an image from AS3 to saved on server I've not needed to involve NetConnection or AMFPHP. An image or BLOB are both just bytes. Consider the method in the link and see if it works for you (especially look at `function saveOnServer`)...

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate it!

Comment: If I were, for instance, to use AMFPHP, is the only visible issue to do with the ByteArray?

Comment: Did you check what's going through the network? It looks like you're returning a resource, which is not supported by Amfphp. You should return an array. Best practice is to use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php Also see https://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/using-a-packet-sniffer/ and https://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/

Comment: Oh, and here's some sample code https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Examples/Php/ExampleServices/UserService.php

Comment: Hi @ArielSommeria-Klein , thanks for your great help. How do you mean I should return an array? Am I not doing so when I call the function and reference the array?

Comment: Sorry, I misread, returning a resource as described here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php is an issue for retrieving data from the DB, but for writing it doesn't matter. Are you sure $ba->data contains something?

Comment: Hi guys, just taught I'd let you know I fixed the problem.. Just send the data as a Base64 String to the blob now